# Querying custom post types by long/lat to find nearest

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a website that allows users to enter their postcode and then they see nearby restaurants. I store the restaurants in a MySQL table and each row contains the restaurant name, address, opening hours, plus longitude and latitude.

When a user enters their postcode I use a Google API to convert the postcode to longitude and latitude and then I use this SQL query ...

```
select 
    locations.*, 
    SQRT(
        69.1*69.1*(latitude - $latitude)*(latitude - $latitude) + 
        53*53*(longitude - $longitude)*(longitude - $longitude)
    ) as distance 
from locations 
having distance <= 100 
order by distance 
limit 100
```

I am now migrating the site to Wordpress. I have created a custom post type called restaurants and have used Advanced Custom Fields to record the same fields - name, address, opening hours and longitude and latitude. I am storing the longitude and latitude in separate fields.

I can make use of `WP_Query` to query all the restaurants:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'restaurants' ) );
```

But how can I amend my `WP_Query` call to allow me to search and sort restaurants by proximity to the supplied longitude and latitude?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VA79 is right and this would be pretty complex, doing the sql joins and stuff.

**I found a solution which is very simple and easy to implement.**

1.
First you need to install this plugin:
https://mg.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-google-maps-radius-search/

2.
In the functions.php of this(!) plugin in line 40, you have to set the name of your advanced custom field in the variable $address.

3.
In the acf_gms.class.php of this plugin in line 163, you have to set the name of your field again in the $address variable.

4.
Now you have to save the posts, that have the Google Maps Field form Advanced Custom Fields set and therefore have a longitute and a latitude value. This is important, otherwise the new created database table (thanks to the plugin) will not have the values in it.

5.
After saving you have a new table in your database with Post ID, Long and Lat Value. Thanks to the plugin, great.

I'm now assuming you want to have form fields on an post archive page, where you can enter the address and it outputs the posts in a order, in which the closest post is shown first, the next closest post next and so on. You want to find the nearest, so I guess this is what you are looking for.

The following code should be entered in your archive.php file. Please replace the API key with yours.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('location');
      var options = {
        types: ['(regions)'],
    };
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

As you see, we are getting the location, long and lat values from form fields. So the form looks like this and can be placed in the archive php file.

```
<form id="yourform">
    <div>
        <input id="location" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Postcode and place of residence" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
        <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" />
        <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" />
    </div> <!-- field -->
    <input type="submit" value="Search nearest" />
</form>
```

If you enter a location the input field with id "location", google maps will suggest places. When you submit the form, the script we started with will use this location and get the long and lat values. With the hidden inputs this values will be posted to the URL as parameters (?lng=...&lat=...).

With our plugin running and the new database table you will get the posts ordered by the distance to your entered location.

That's it. If you have any questions, don't mind asking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all wordpress stores your custom posts in the wp_posts table and the acf fields are stored in the wp_post_meta table, so you would have to join them with sql in some way. If i understand you correct you could use the wpdb class that allows you to make your own sql queries. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 1):

I think the best bet is this

1. create a text-area acf field in your Theme Options give it hint of `<style>.keepitsecret-keeptitsafe{display:none;}</style>` and give the that field itself a class of "keepitsecret-keeptitsafe" so it hides from front-end user
2. run like a daily cronjob (how often are these restaurants changing locatoins, you know?) to get all the POST_IDs of your posts with an array of lat&lon which should look something like this: [1=>['lat'=>12123123, 'lon'=>12123123132], 3=>['lat'=>12123123, 'lon'=>12123123132]] and store this as json in the previously made Option ACField. (hint: when you retrieve, make sure to pass false to avoid formatting your json ) `get_field('latlon', 'option', false)` // as a bakcup, save to file if you'd like

```
    $allyourcustomposts = get_posts(['post_type'=>['whateveryourcustompostis'], 'posts_per_page'=> -1]);
    foreach($allyourcustomposts as $post) {
        $lat = get_field('lat', $post->ID);
        $lon = get_field('lon', $post->ID);
        if($lat && $lon && $lat != '' && $lon != '') {
            $savior[$post->ID] = ['lat'=>$lat,'lon'=>$lon];
        }
    }
    if(count($savior) > 0) {
        $json = json_encode($savior);
        update_field('field_5b04b0544d603', $json, 'option');
        @file_put_contents('savior.json', $json);
    }
```

3. create a function that finds the distance between 2 locations with an optional $distance = 0 parameter.
4. now when you search, iterate thorugh all the posts from the stored POST_ID=>lat&lon array save a separate array of $finals[post_id] = distance
5. asort the array, then array_keys to get all the post ids in the order

and finally in your wp_query to $args['post__in'] = $finalspostids,

and if you need to to be ordered by the order which it's in the $finalpostids, the $args['orderby'] = 'post__in'

little bit of starter code:

```
    function orderByNearby($lat, $lon, $arrayOfLatLonPosts, $distance = 0) {
        $orderedIds = [];
        if($lat != 0 && $lon != 0 && $arrayOfLatLonPosts && count($arrayOfLatLonPosts) > 0) {
            foreach($arrayOfLatLonPosts as $post_id => $arrayOfLatLonPost) {
                $dist = @closeEnough($arrayOfLatLonPost->lat, $arrayOfLatLonPost->lon, $lat, $lon);
                if($distance > 0) {
                    if($dist  0) {
        asort($ids);
        $args['post__in'] = array_keys($ids);
        $args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    } else {
        $args['s'] = 'this is hilariously monstreous stupendous name search that will never and probably will ever match!!! so blah blah blah blah blah';
    }
```

so when you pass the $distance variable, you sometimes will get 0 results in that case just pass extrememly long search text to return empty.

ps. first time answering question here, the horrendous editor is bunkers!!!

good luck.

Comment: closeEnough function is this

`function closeEnough($post_lat, $post_lon, $user_lat, $user_lon, $length = 5) {
 $theta = $post_lon - $user_lon;
 $dist = sin(deg2rad($post_lat)) * sin(deg2rad($user_lat)) +  cos(deg2rad($post_lat)) * cos(deg2rad($user_lat)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
 $dist = acos($dist);
 $dist = rad2deg($dist);
 $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
 return $miles;
}`